# Inner join two mysql tables using php with where clauses

Tags: php, html, mysql

I populate mysql tables dynamically with foreign key, so am using inner join to search the table so that any of the records that are selected will display on the table with each value.

table 1 (`stock_details`):

```
`stid`, `prod_name`, `cat_name`, `rate`
```

table 2 (`stock_level`):

```
`id`, `stid`, `opening`, `closing` `stock_details id` (foreign key).
```

Field in `stock_details` are displayed dynamically with a drop-down on my HTML form.

I want if I select for instance `stock` as `prod_name`, `crate` as `cat_name` and `2000` as `rate`, then let only this selected item display.

I am not getting any errors, but no results either.

See my SQL query below:

```
<?php
//checking if data is submitted
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

//select data from tables
$sql = "SELECT sd.prod_name, sd.cat_name, sd.rate, sl.closing 
FROM 
  stock_details AS sd 
  INNER JOIN stock_level AS sl ON sd.stid=sl.stid 
WHERE 
  sd.prod_name='$prod_name' 
  AND sd.cat_name='$cat_name' 
  AND sd.rate='$rate' 
ORDER BY 
  sd.stid desc 
LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
```

...

```
//fetch data from db tables and display on the browser
<?php
if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
?>

<!-- displaying data fetch from db tables to the browser -->
<tr>
  <td><?= $row['sd.prod_name']?></td>
  <td><?= $row['sd.cat_name']?></td>
  <td><?= $row['sd.rate']?></td>
  <td><?= $row['sl.closing']?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where are `$prod_name`, `$cat_name` and `$rate` coming from in this code? It's bunclear how you populated them. Have you tried `var_dump($sql);` to see if your SQL query looks accurate, and then tried to run that directly in MySQL (e.g. using Workbench or PHPMyAdmin) to see if it produces the expected results? This is some basic extra information you should have investigated and provided already.

Comment: l have a lines of code that fetch each of this 3 fields from the database table through dropdown and it work fine. the second line of code without condition, it fetch all the records from the tables but that is not what l want. l only need the selected one from the dropdown to display on the table when l click submit button.

Comment: Ok. So, have you done what I said, and tried to verify what query is actually being executed? Does the query appear as you expected? Does it work when you run it direct in MySQL? Since we cannot see what variables you are supplying, and we cannot see the data in your database, there is no way for us to know whether we should expect the query to return any results or not. You need to test and verify that yourself. Either that or you need to give us a data sample.

Comment: However, I would note that `INNER JOIN stock_level AS sl ON sd.stid=sl.stid` looks potentially problematic. In your description you said that the foreign key field in the `stock_level` table was `stock_details id`, not `stid`. are they the same thing, or two different fields? It's actually a bit unclear.

Comment: stid is the id for stock_details table and the stock_level id is stlid and also contain stid as a constrain foreign key